# Handlebars typeahead count results showing

Tags: jquery, ajax, handlebars.js, typeahead.js

I'm trying to show the amount of results showing per subject using handlebars in typeahead, like this:

[image: example]

Here's the code I have so far:

```js
var clients = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('client_name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'clients.php?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

var contacts = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('contact_firstname'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'contacts.php?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

var tasks = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('assignment_subject'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'tasks.php?query=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

clients.initialize();
contacts.initialize();
tasks.initialize();

$("#clients").typeahead({
  hint: true,
  // highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},{
  name: 'clients',
  displayKey: 'client_name',
  source: clients.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: Handlebars.compile('<div class="search_header">Kundkort <span>(<span class="test">{{#each client_name}} {{counter @index}} {{@index}} {{/each}}</span>) träffar</span></div>'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><span class="act_link"><a href="?p=crm&client_id={{client_id}}&action=view">{{client_name}}</a></span> <div class="client_type">{{#ifCond client_type "==" 1}} A-kund {{else}} {{#ifCond client_type "==" 2}} Återförsäljare {{/ifCond}} {{#ifCond client_type "==" 3}} Leverantör {{/ifCond}} {{#ifCond client_type "==" 4}} Partner {{/ifCond}} {{#ifCond client_type "==" 5}} Prospekt {{/ifCond}} {{/ifCond}}</div></div>')
  }
},{
  name: 'contacts',
  displayKey: 'contact_firstname',
  source: contacts.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: Handlebars.compile('<div class="search_header">Personer <span>(<span class="test">{{c_count}}</span>) träffar</span></div>'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><span class="act_link"><a href="?p=crm&client_id={{client_id}}&action=view">{{contact_firstname}} {{contact_lastname}}</a></span> <div class="client_type">{{client_name}}</div></div>')
  }
},{
  name: 'tasks',
  displayKey: 'assignment_subject',
  source: tasks.ttAdapter(),
  templates: {
    header: Handlebars.compile('<div class="search_header">Uppgifter <span>(<span class="test">{{tasks.id.length}}</span>) träffar</span></div>'),
    suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<div><span class="act_link"><a href="?p=tasks&id={{id}}&action=view">{{assignment_subject}}</a></span></div>')
  }      
});
```

I've been trying different methods and I can't seem to figure it out.

---

**EDIT**

jsFiddle without working results http://jsfiddle.net/0n0b2ue4/2/

jsFiddle with data http://jsfiddle.net/0n0b2ue4/3/

Comment: Can you come up with a runnable version in jsFiddle or Stacksnippets?  That would help the onboarding of new people trying to solve your problem much quicker, instead of making them re-write your html and appropriate links to external libraries.  Also, instead of just including a wall of javascript, is there a particular section that you are trying to work through and having trouble?

Comment: To show people a runnable version requires my external libraries, html and stuff. But if I want to make a jsFiddle of this it requires a lot of editing and explaining. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is that the number between the brackets update by results showing from the typeahead plugin. @KyleMit

Comment: I'm totally there with you that it would require a lot of work to setup a good question.  But i think it's a reasonable expectation when answer will also require a fair amount of work. Nobody's forcing you to, but good questions remove external dependencies so other people can learn from them too in the future.  For example, you could, for the purposes of the question, use a local array instead of getting it from `clients.php`, because the part that you're trying to get answered doesn't have to do with ajax.  It **will** take work, but someone's gonna have to do it.

Comment: Edited my question, added two links. I tried my best, hope it helps you to understand the problem. @KyleMit

Comment: it's a good first try, but there's plenty more to clean up.  Neither of the examples actually work.  Have you tried to run them?  Also, please try to remove *anything* that doesn't immediately pertain to your question.  You could get rid of all the suggestion templates as they are not the primary focus of your question.  All work toward stripping down the question into an [mcve] is time well spent.  Either way, I hope my answer below solves your question. I've removed a lot of code to just get the minimal amount working so it's clear which pieces are moving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [typeahead docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md), the context passed into the `header` template:

> will contain `query` and `suggestions`

`Suggestions` contains a list of the current suggestions for that data set and exposes a length property.  So just use `{{suggestions.length}}` in the handlebars template for your header (not `{{count}}`).

#### Here's a demo in Stack Snippets.

```js
// constructs the suggestion engine
var clients = new Bloodhound({
    local: ["A Client", "AA Client", "BC Client"],
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
var contacts = new Bloodhound({
    local: ["BA Contact", "BB Contact", "CC Contact"],
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
var tasks = new Bloodhound({
    local: ["A Client", "AA Client", "BC Client"],
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

// initialize typeahead by passing in options and data
$("#clients").typeahead({
    hint: true,
    minLength: 1
}, {
    name: 'clients',
    source: clients,
    templates: {
        header: Handlebars.compile($("#clients-header").html())
    }
}, {
    name: 'contacts',
    source: contacts,
    templates: {
        header: Handlebars.compile($("#contacts-header").html())
    }
}, {
    name: 'tasks',
    source: tasks,
    templates: {
        header: Handlebars.compile($("#tasks-header").html())
    }
});
```

```css
.search_header {
  margin-left: 6px;
}
div.tt-menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.3/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="clients" class="typeahead" />

<!-- Templates -->
<script id="clients-header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <strong class="search_header">
    Clients <small>({{suggestions.length}}) results</small>
  </strong>
</script>
<script id="contacts-header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <strong class="search_header">
    Contacts  <small>({{suggestions.length}}) results</small>
  </strong>
</script>
<script id="tasks-header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <strong class="search_header">
    Tasks  <small>({{suggestions.length}}) results</small>
  </strong>
</script>
```

Comment: Seriously? I tried `{{suggestions.length}}` before and it didn't work.. Anyways thanks a lot for your help. Next time I should read the docs again and try it once more.